# DC/OS Cassandra Service Doesn't work after Restart Cluster

Tags: azure, cassandra, mesosphere, dcos

I'm using DC/OS 1.8 when i installed Cassandra Service from the DC/OS Universe.

If i stop & start my cluster (master and all nodes) the service doesn't start and i have to uninstall the service, delete all file in the agents node and after install Cassandra service.

P.S. My Cassandra Cluster is installed on Azure with Azure Container Service.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: well, can you at least provide logs, I don't think many people here have telepathic capacity

Answer (score 0):

Few questions before we even go further investigation.
1. Have you seen tried to reproduce the issue ?  How it is like ?
2. Have you explored DC/OS 1.8 without Azure ? Maybe it is DC/OS issue.

In general, we (Azure Container Service) will have the issue if DC/OS itself is buggy. It is always worth to mine the known issues on DC/OS github first. And yes, we need log